# How can I send data with LWIP periodically in a proper way?

Tags: c, tcp, server, client, lwip

I am trying to send some data with LWIP from a microcontroller periodically to a client. I started off with the code from an Atmel-Studio example called "lwIP Raw HTTP basic example". After sending around 100 objects, the connection breaks.

I am sending a heartbeat-signal and another object every 100ms from the client to the microcontroller. My receive-callback-function is called from lwIP then. Sending the data this way works fine.

But I want to send the data uncoupled from receiving data. In my attempt, I am sending the data with the same functions I also use in the callback context, but in the main while-loop. Im using a pointer to the tcp_pcb from the initialization in own_init(). When the connection breaks, the state of the pcb is changed from ESTABLISHED to CLOSED. My suspicion is that i am using the pcb-pointers wrongly but i cant come up with another way to do it. Thank you!

```
int main(void)
{    
    ...

    /* Bring up the ethernet interface & initialize timer0, channel0. */
    init_ethernet();


    /* Bring up the server. */
    struct tcp_pcb* pcb;
    pcb=own_init();


    uint32_t sendInterval=100; //ms
    uint32_t lastTimeSFSsent=0;
    uint32_t lastTimeHeartbeatSent=0;
    uint32_t currentTime=0;
    uint8_t is_connected=0;

    initSFS();

    while(1)
    {

        currentTime=sys_get_ms();

        if(currentTime > lastTimeSFSsent + sendInterval && pcb->state==ESTABLISHED){
            lastTimeSFSsent=sys_get_ms();
            sendSFS(pcb);
        }

        if(currentTime> lastTimeHeartbeatSent + sendInterval && pcb->state==ESTABLISHED){
            lastTimeHeartbeatSent=sys_get_ms();
            sendHeartbeat(pcb);

        }
        ethernet_task();


    }    
}
```

---

This is different from the example code:

```
struct tcp_pcb* own_init(void)
{
    struct tcp_pcb *pcb;
    struct tcp_pcb *tpcb;

    pcb = tcp_new();
    tcp_bind(pcb, IP_ADDR_ANY, 5005);
    tpcb = tcp_listen(pcb);
    tcp_accept(tpcb, own_accept);

    return pcb;

}
```